# Limit download of data from SQL in Android app

Tags: android, mysql

I have an app that gets "all" records from a SQL database via a web service. The app is designed to update all data from the database onOpen. However the database is getting large and now I only want the app to update NEW records.

**Current state of app:**

App installed and opened ...app downloads 1000 records from SQL       database. App opened

2nd time.... app downloads 1000 records (total      refresh of data) App opened 3rd

time.... app downloads 1000 records      (total refresh of data)

**What I want:**

App installed and opened ...app downloads 1000 records from SQL database and records date/time of update.

everytime after..... app downloads only records newer or updated since last update. App then records date/time to reference on next update.

App also has a menu item to conduct a complete refresh upon users request.

I assume that I need to add a field to my sql table. What datatype should I use? Is there a [last update] auto dat/time data type?

Is there a better way to do this?

Please help, I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

UPDATE: Since I am not seeing any quick fixes, what about if I have just add a date field to my database and manually add a date? Then use 2 separate PHP functions (1) Get all (2) Get new? If I manually edit a record in the database, I will need to also manually update the date stamp field. Seems like there would be an easier way? Anyone got a better solution?

*UPDATE #2***

What if I just change my app to parse the data via JSON? Would that decrease the app update time from 20 minutes to maybe 20 seconds?

***Final Update***
For anyone that might have this problem. Here is how I fixed it. I added a new field to mySQL database with a datatype of TIMESTAMP. My app records the time of update (GMT) so in my PHP file, I use a function that fetches all records newer than the last udate. It works great.

Comment: Does the web service have an auto-incrementing id field?

Comment: Yes. An ID number for each record. Only thing is that if I merely update a record, I want that to fetch in the update as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution you suggested in your UPDATE section is the optimal one. Get the latest possible date from your app via a query like:

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM table;
```

Then use that value in your request url. You'll have to write the PHP function that returns all records with a newer timestamp.

Comment: Ah, Yeah..okay. I sure wish there was a better way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite does not keep track of records insertion order so there is no way to get "latest & newest" unless:
1) Your database record contains a field of auto-increment type
2) Your database contains insertion time.

In the first case, assuming `_id` is an auto-increment index, and the last record you retrieved has `_id = 1000`, your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ... AND _id > 1000;
```

Comment: 1 ID int(11) No None AUTO_INCREMENT 2 Name varchar(35) utf8_unicode_ci 3 Latitude float(10,6) 4 Longitude float(10,6)

Comment: ID field is an auto increment. But how would that help in identifying if I edited an older record?

Comment: You don't have chance to change db structure?

Comment: Yes. Sure I can change the database structure. When I publish a new update to my app, existing users will be forced to reinstall. Why?

Comment: You can publish new software update, and you can update the table & structure and records on the fly when new version is run 1st time. The db has a version field. If you are using `SqliteOpenHelper` class, you should overwrite `onUpgrade()` method.

Comment: Check this for example: http://www.google.com/codesearch#oOy_5JrVRNM/trunk/packages/apps/Browser/src/com/android/browser/BrowserProvider.java&ct=rc&cd=4

Comment: Ah, yes, I understand the sqliteOpenHelp ....thats what I will need to do, when I change the database structure. But is there an auto increment datestamp field in a mySQL database?